# How to show total when field is expanded in pivot table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

How can I add a subtotal to an *expanded* field in a pivot table? (It shows fine when collapsed).

In the image below, I'd like to see "8" (6+2) in the highlighted cell (B2).

[Image of what I'd like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFAUy.png)

Comment: You need to turn on `subtotals` for rows

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer but this link will help  https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-subtotals.html

Comment: Thanks @peterH. Turns out, turning `subtotals` on is in the "Design" tab.

Comment: when working with pivot table, I prefer to use `tabular view` when working with sub totals, Google how to use that you may find it useful also